# getting elements and attributes from xml using java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am having trouble to figure out how to get attributes and elements of xml tag inside another xml tag
For example:
    If I have this xml part:

```
<echo>-----------------------------------------</echo>
<echo>Applying ${app} .msi file... </echo>
<echo>-----------------------------------------</echo>

<exec executable="start" vmlauncher="false">
<arg line='/wait ${basedir}\Installation\${pkgname}.msi' />
</exec>
</target>


<target name="repackage" depends="program,update,move_shortcuts"
description="Installs and updates ${app}" />

<target name="program" unless="executableExists">
<echo>---------------------------------------------------------</echo>
<echo> Installing ${app} </echo>
<echo>---------------------------------------------------------</echo>

<unzip src="${install_pkg}" dest="c:\" /> 

<echo>---------------------------------------------------------</echo>
<echo> ...PROGRAM INSTALLATION IS COMPLETE. </echo>
<echo>---------------------------------------------------------</echo>
<sleep seconds="1" />
</target>
```

and I want to get to print out something like

```
 Current Element :target
 name : install
 depends : repackage
 unless : 
 description : 
 command: exec executable = start , vmlauncher = false
       arg line='/wait ${basedir}\Installation\${pkgname}.msi'
```

Right now I am using this method 
    NodeList tarList = doc.getElementsByTagName("target");

```
System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("");
         for (int tarTemp = 0; tarTemp < tarList.getLength(); tarTemp++) {
            Node tarNode = tarList.item(tarTemp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
               + tarNode.getNodeName());



            if (tarNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element eElement = (Element) tarNode;
               System.out.println("name : " 
                  + eElement.getAttribute("name"));
               System.out.println("depends : " 
                      + eElement.getAttribute("depends"));
               System.out.println("unless : " 
                          + eElement.getAttribute("unless"));
               System.out.println("description : " 
                          + eElement.getAttribute("description"));
               System.out.println(
                            eElement.getTextContent());


               }

         }
```

and that yield this output

```
 Current Element :target
 name : install
 depends : repackage
 unless : 
 description :
```

Now if I want to include the command inside this output, I can't since the tarList only looks for elements and attributes within the tag name "target".

Comment: Why are you doing this with Java code? It would be much easier in XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse nodes of the tag you want include within `target` in the same way you handle `target`:

```
if (tarNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) tarNode;
    NodeList internalNodes = eElement .getElementsByTagName("commmand");
    //process internalNodes 
    for (Element el : internalNodes)
    { 
       ...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Got it thanks, this sucks if you have multiple different name tags then you will have to code to handle each of them.... :((